# How to render images using <img> tag in angular 7 project?

Tags: html, image, angular7, src

I am required to display an image in an angular 7 application using this information:

company {
logo: 'https://static.wixstatic.com / media / dc0d61_854a54df0f1049bcbb20e2f9a64236eb.png / v1 / fill / w_112, h_112, al_c, usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/ dc0d61_854a54df0f1049bcbb20e 2f9a64236eb.png',
}

To my understanding the logo value has to be provided in the src attribute of image tag in the template file as follows:

```
<img width="300" alt="Company Logo" src="{{company.logo}}"/>
```

First question: is this the rigth way to render an image in angular7 app?

Second question: should i see the image that is required to display when i visit the given http address (which I am not, rather I am getting 404 Not Found error when tried to visit this src adddress)

P.S I am not getting the image displayed when tried above

Comment: Have you confirmed it is the right url you are using? It looks a bit strange with all the whitespace and commas... Moreover you must use a property binding for the source `[src]="company.logo"`

Comment: when i tried the address by removing the whitespaces, its still giving the same 404 Not Found error

Answer (score 0):

In order to render the image, the images should be placed in the assets folder of the application. Rest if the image remains the same then yes, it's the correct way to render the images in the Angular7 app.

Try to place the image in the assets folder and update the path. It will work.